# PHP help validating set properties

Tags: php, class, validation, methods

I'm creating a PHP program that has a student class with different properties such as name, id, address, etc. I'm not understanding why my validation in my Set Properties section is not updating correctly. The state, zip code, and age are updating, but the rest of them are not. I have no idea why my student id is displaying 274. I don't even get where it got that from. Please explain why my validation is not working correctly.

```
function set_student_name($value)
{
    $error_message = true;

    (ctype_alpha($value) && strlen($value) <= 20) ? $this->student_name = $value : $error_message = false;

    return $error_message;
}
```

This is what I thought it meant:
If value is a string AND value is <= 20 THEN value == student_name.

Ok here is the rest of my code. There are two files. The first on is the class.

```
class Student
{

    // --------------------------------Properties-----------------------------------
    private $student_id      = 6212;
    private $student_name    = 'No Name';
    private $student_address = 'No Address';
    private $student_state   = 'No State';
    private $student_zip     = 0;
    private $student_age     = 0;
    private $error_message   = '??';

    // --------------------------------Constructor----------------------------------
    public function __construct($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $value5, $value6)
    {
        $id_error             = $this->set_student_id($value1) == true ? 'TRUE,' : 'FALSE,';
        $name_error           = $this->set_student_name($value2) == true ? 'TRUE,' : 'FALSE,';
        $address_error        = $this->set_student_address($value3) == true ? 'TRUE,' : 'FALSE,';
        $state_error          = $this->set_student_state($value4) == true ? 'TRUE,' : 'FALSE,';
        $zip_error            = $this->set_student_zip($value5) == true ? 'TRUE,' : 'FALSE,';
        $age_error            = $this->set_student_age($value6) == true ? 'TRUE,' : 'FALSE,';
        $this->$error_message = $id_error . $name_error . $address_error . $state_error . $zip_error . $age_error;
    }

    // ---------------------------------toString------------------------------------
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->$error_message;
    }

    // --------------------------------Set Methods----------------------------------
    public function set_student_id($value)
    {
        $error_message                                                              = true;
        (ctype_digit($value) && ($value > 0 && $value <= 9999)) ? $this->student_id = $value : $error_message = false;

        return $error_message;
    }

    public function set_student_name($value)
    {
        $error_message                                                      = true;
        (ctype_alpha($value) && strlen($value) <= 20) ? $this->student_name = $value : $error_message = false;

        return $error_message;
    }

    public function set_student_address($value)
    {
        $error_message                                                         = true;
        (ctype_alpha($value) && strlen($value) <= 20) ? $this->student_address = $value : $error_message = false;

        return $error_message;
    }

    public function set_student_state($value)
    {
        $error_message                                                       = true;
        (ctype_alpha($value) && strlen($value) <= 20) ? $this->student_state = $value : $error_message = false;

        return $error_message;
    }

    public function set_student_zip($value)
    {
        $error_message                                                                = true;
        (ctype_digit($value) && ($value > 0 && $value <= 99999)) ? $this->student_zip = $value : $error_message = false;

        return $error_message;
    }

    public function set_student_age($value)
    {
        $error_message                                                              = true;
        (ctype_digit($value) && ($value > 0 && $value <= 100)) ? $this->student_age = $value : $error_message = false;

        return $error_message;
    }

    // --------------------------------Get Methods----------------------------------
    public function get_student_id()
    {
        return $this->student_id;
    }

    public function get_student_name()
    {
        return $this->student_name;
    }

    public function get_student_address()
    {
        return $this->student_address;
    }

    public function get_student_state()
    {
        return $this->student_state;
    }

    public function get_student_zip()
    {
        return $this->student_zip;
    }

    public function get_student_age()
    {
        return $this->student_age;
    }

    public function get_properties()
    {
        return "$this->student_id, $this->student_name, $this->student_address, $this->student_state, $this->student_zip, $this->student_age.";
    }
}
```

This is the second file that calls the class:

```
require_once 'student.php';

$collegeStudent = new Student('0422', 'John Smith', '315 Home St', 'Georgia', '30204', '20');

list($id_error, $name_error, $address_error, $state_error, $zip_error, $age_error) = explode(',', $collegeStudent);

print $id_error == 'TRUE' ? 'Student ID update successful<br/>' : 'Student ID update not successful<br/>';
print $name_error == 'TRUE' ? 'Name update successful<br/>' : 'Name update not successful<br/>';
print $address_error == 'TRUE' ? 'Address update successful<br/>' : 'Address update not successful<br/>';
print $state_error == 'TRUE' ? 'State update successful<br/>' : 'State update not successful<br/>';
print $zip_error == 'TRUE' ? 'Zip code update successful<br/>' : 'Zip code update not successful<br/>';
print $age_error == 'TRUE' ? 'Age update successful<br/>' : 'Age update not successful<br/>';

// ------------------------------ Set Properties--------------------------------
print '------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>';
$student_error_message = $collegeStudent->set_student_id(0422);
print $student_error_message == true ? 'Student ID update successful<br />' : 'Student ID update not successful<br />';

$student_error_message = $collegeStudent->set_student_name('John Smith');
print $student_error_message == true ? 'Name update successful<br />' : 'Name update not successful<br/>';

$student_error_message = $collegeStudent->set_student_address('315 Home St');
print $student_error_message == true ? 'Address update successful<br />' : 'Address update not successful<br/>';

$student_error_message = $collegeStudent->set_student_state('Georgia');
print $student_error_message == true ? 'State update successful<br />' : 'State update not successful<br/>';

$student_error_message = $collegeStudent->set_student_zip(30204);
print $student_error_message == true ? 'Zip code update successful<br />' : 'Zip code update not successful<br/>';

$student_error_message = $collegeStudent->set_student_age(20);
print $student_error_message == true ? 'Age update successful<br />' : 'Age update not successful<br/>';
print '------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>';

// ------------------------------ Get Properties--------------------------------
print $collegeStudent->get_student_id() . '<br />';
print $collegeStudent->get_student_name() . '<br />';
print $collegeStudent->get_student_address() . '<br />';
print $collegeStudent->get_student_state() . '<br />';
print $collegeStudent->get_student_zip() . '<br />';
print $collegeStudent->get_student_age() . '<br />';

$student_properties = $collegeStudent->get_properties();
list($student_id, $student_name, $student_address, $student_state,
    $student_zip, $student_age) = explode(',', $student_properties);

print "Student ID is $student_id. Student name is $student_name. Student address
is $student_address. Student state is $student_state. Student zip is $student_zip.
Student age is $student_age.";
```

**Here is my output:**

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Two part question, two part answer:

To fix the name validation you could strip out the whitespace with `preg_replace` first and then check if the value contains only alpha characters. But be warned, any name with an apostrophe (e.g. O'Donne) will not validate.

```
function set_student_name($value)
{
    $error_message = true;

    (ctype_alpha(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $value)) && strlen($value) <= 20) ? $this->student_name = $value : $error_message = false;

    return $error_message;
}
```

Secondly, you are seeing 274 because you wrote the number as an octal. PHP recognizes any literal number with a leading 0 as an octal (meaning base 8). If you need to store the student ID with a leading 0, you could store it as a string instead, or you could pad it with additional 0s with your getter function.

```
public function get_student_id()
{
    return str_pad($this->student_id, 4, "0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working! I'll keep that in mind. My age in set properties is not updating. I'm looking into that right now.

Comment: That's because it's expecting a string http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php. You are passing an integer.